# Wordpress Visually Group / Separate Outputted Posts From Categories using query_posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my wordpress site, I'm outputting posts sorted by category ascending and this is working fine.

**The code for accomplishing this so far is:**

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1,2,3&showposts=5&orderby=category&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt() ?>
  </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Right now all the posts are displayed as one group, sorted by category ascended which is great ... but I'm trying to visually separate the categories.

So, my code right now would work smth like:

```
Cat1 Post1 Cat1 Post2 Cat2 Post1 Cat2 Post2 Cat2 Post3 Cat3 Post1 ... and so on
```

I want to separate them like this:

```
CATEGORY ONE:
Cat1 Post1 Cat1 Post2 

CATEGORY TWO:
Cat2 Post1 Cat2 Post2 Cat2 Post3 

CATEGORY THREE:
Cat3 Post1 ... and so on
```

Is this a paramater I can add to the query_posts loop or something?  Seems like something easy to accomplish but I have no idea how to!  Any helps appreciated.

Comment: If these posts only get assigned to one of the given categories use a little conditional code inside the loop based on the result of `if( in_category( 'your-cat') )`. You could use a switch, or just store the current category in var and check that with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using three separate query_posts to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's how to do it. You can do the same thing with my SEO Siloing plugin, but you would definitely need to use three separate calls to it, which is what you've done.

Comment: Using three queries in place of a singular one is not a good way to do it, your page load is slower, your server resource usage is higher, etc.. a little conditional logic inside the loop would be much better and allow you to stick to using one query.

Comment: In this particular case, yes, because the posts are being ordered by category. However, in most cases you want to order the posts within a category by date or title. Three queries will make for simpler code. And if you have posts with multiple categories, the separate queries will ensure that the posts show up correctly in each category. Just my opinion.

Comment: As the user said in the opening question, the ordering is currently as desired, the only remaining aspect was to create some seperation between each group visually(you don't need extra queries to do that). Seeing as i don't have the time to provide my own answer i'll agree it solves the problem(i simply don't think it's the best or a necessary approach).